# Approximation of $f\in L_p$ with simple function $f_n\in L_p$

Tags: metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

Let us use the definition of Lebesgue integral on $X,\mu(X)<\infty$ as the limit$$\int_X fd\mu:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_nd\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_{n,k}\mu(A_{n,k})$$where $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of simple, i.e. taking countably (infinitely or finitely) many values $y_{n,k}$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$, functions $f_n:X\to\mathbb{C}$ uniformly converging to $f$, and $\{y_{n,k}\}=f_n(A_{n,k})$ where $\forall i\ne j\quad A_{n,i}\cap A_{n,j}=\emptyset$.

I know that if any sequence $\{f_n\}\subset L_p(X,\mu)$, $p\geq 1$ uniformly converges to $f$ then [it also converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012085/convergence-in-l-p-and-elsewhere) with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ to the same limit, which is therefore an element of $L_p(X,\mu)$.

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis* (1963 Graylock edition, p.85) that *hence an arbitrary function* $f\in L_2$ *can be approximated* [with respect to norm $\|\cdot\|_2$, I suspect] *with arbitrary simple functions belonging to* $L_2$.

I do not understand how the last statement is deduced. If it were true, I would find the general case for $L_p$, $p\geq 1$, even more interesting. I understand that if $f\in L_p\subset L_1$ then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a simple function $f_n\in L_1$ such that $\forall x\in A\quad |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$ and then, for all $p\geq 1$, $\|f-f_n\|_p<\varepsilon$, but how to find $f_n\in L_p$ (if $p=2$ or in general $p>1$)?

Can anybody explain such a statement? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: It is impossible to approximate an arbitrary $L^p$ function uniformly by step functions. But we can approximate a *bounded* $L^p$ function in such a way, and then approximate the original function by bounded functions (truncation). Or do it all in one step [like here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/475722/). One can use the monotone convergence theorem, or dominated convergence theorem, to justify passing to the limit in the integral.

Comment: Thank you very much! Quite shocked: Kolmogorov and Fomin in the original text, and Silverman in the translation, reapeat and use such a property, without assuming $f$'s boundedness, to prove the separability of $L_1$ and $L_2$...

Comment: (My first comment predates the edit that added the possibility of simple functions having countably many values.)

Comment: Sorry, excuse me, I should have written " simple, i.e. taking countably (infinitely or finitely) [...]" instead of " simple, i.e. taking countably [...]" without any specification before: I've only very recently realised that the usual definition is with a finite number of values, while Kolmogorov-Fomin's, which is the text I'm following, use the def. with "$n$ or $\aleph_0$" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many sources, simple functions are those measurable functions that have a finite set of values. But here a countably infinite set of values is allowed.  This allows one easily approximate any measurable function $f$ uniformly by simple functions: for example, let
$$
f_n(x) = \frac{\lfloor n f(x)\rfloor }{n}
$$
and observe that $f-\frac{1}{n}\le f_n\le f$ everywhere. On a finite measure space, this implies $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ norm for every $p\in [1,\infty]$.

Comment: And $f_n\in L_p$ because $|f_n|\leq |f|+1/n$. Interestingly, Kolmogorov and Fomin, in the  vol. 2 of 1963 Graylock ed. of "Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis" shows that a simple function with countably infinite values can be arbitrarily approximated by simple functions with $n$ values and in exercice (c), p. 91, says that it can be done for any $f\in L_p$. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Not "arbitrarily" -- it can be approximated in $L^p$ for $p<\infty$, but not uniformly.