# Approximation of measurable function by simple functions 2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

consider the measure space (X,$\mathcal{M}$,$\mu$).imagine the non-negative and Lebesgue measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given. Prove that there is a sequence of simple functions 
$$\lim_{i \to\infty} f_i(x)=f(x), \forall x \in X$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format, for future reference.

Comment: You say Lebesgue measurable, but you state your question for an arbitrary measure space. You mean just "measurable". Lebesgue measurable is for a specific measurable space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Approximation of measurable function by simple functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475722/approximation-of-measurable-function-by-simple-functions)